# How to delete / deactivate a rogue MFA device in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I introduced a policy that requires the users in a group to enable MFA. After enabling the policy I logged into an user account (user-foo) to try it out and apparently created a kind of a rogue MFA device when I aborted the setup of a virtual MFA device.

This led to the following error when the user tried to connect his MFA device:

[image: AWS console error when trying to connect MFA device]

Here is a list of the MFA devices. For comparison I added the output of user-bar with a correctly initialized MFA device.

```
$ aws iam list-virtual-mfa-devices
{
    "VirtualMFADevices": [
        {
            "SerialNumber": "arn:aws:iam::123456789010:mfa/user-foo"
        },
        {
            "SerialNumber": "arn:aws:iam::123456789010:mfa/user-bar",
            "User": {
                "Path": "/",
                "UserName": "user-bar",
                "UserId": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU",
                "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789010:user/user-bar",
                "CreateDate": "2020-07-02T09:45:21Z",
                "PasswordLastUsed": "2020-07-03T08:56:47Z"
            },
            "EnableDate": "2020-07-02T11:07:07Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, only the serial number for the MFA device of user-foo shows up. To delete the entry on the CLI also the user name is required. So I logged in as admin and assigned my phone as MFA device. Now the device showed up properly, but after deleting it with:

```
$ deactivate-mfa-device --user-name user-foo --serial-number arn:aws:iam::123456789010:mfa/user-foo
```

It appears again with its serial number without the user:

```
$ aws iam list-virtual-mfa-devices
{
    "VirtualMFADevices": [
        {
            "SerialNumber": "arn:aws:iam::123456789010:mfa/user-foo"
        },
        [...]
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do what the dialog box said, and log in as administrator. Or update your user policy to allow users to delete their devices (probably a bad idea).

Comment: Also, note that the MFA device `SerialNumber` is tied to the particular user.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am aware that the SerialNumber is tied to the user and, as described, I tried to do this as an admin from the CLI. But apparently the removal of a MFA device is only possible from the console. Strange but okay...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, pretty easy solution: It works if the MFA device is deleted in the console. For some reason this is not possible from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the process and end it it creates that error and creates a disabled unassigned MFA device. Even though it has the user name in the arn, it is still assigned. It is possible to delete the MFA device from the command line.

aws iam delete-virtual-mfa-device --serial-number arn:aws:iam::123456789010:mfa/user-foo

If the device were enabled you would have to disable it prior to being able to delete it. The completion of setting up an MFA device needs to be done in one pass or will create this error.